# How to implement scenario outlines in scala

Tags: scala, cucumber, outline

We are currently implementing some acceptance tests using Scala.

In cuke, there is a notion of scenario outline.

Does anyone know how to implement this using the FeatureSpec in Scala?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what the feature you want is? Not everyone is familiar with cuke.

Comment: The only real problem with the question is that he wasn't specific about which framework he was testing with, I'm assuming it was ScalaTest.

Comment: Sorry, the framework is ScalaTest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think scenario outline is a cucumber feature, and I'm not sure you should necessarily expect find parity in existing Scala testing libraries.

That being said, I've used cucumber-scala and used scenario outlines in some of my projects, here are the dependencies i used (check for newer versions, and please don't assume this is the end-all way to do this):

```
"com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11-RC1" % "test",
"info.cukes" % "cucumber-core" % "1.1.8" % "test",
"info.cukes" % "cucumber-junit" % "1.1.8" % "test",
"info.cukes" %% "cucumber-scala" % "1.1.8" % "test",
"org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.9.5" % "test"
```

And here is an example of what my runner looked like:

```
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(classOf[Cucumber])
class CucumberRunner {}
```

Here is an example of a given clause loading an outline table:

```
Given("""^some data$""") { (t: DataTable) =>
  val input = t.asMaps(classOf[String], classOf[String])
  // use table data...
}
```

And i took the particulars out, but that was dealing with a gerkin file like this (stored in `main/test/resources` in the same package):

```
Background:
  Given some data
    |  a |    b |     c |         d |
    |  1 |    a |   0.0 | s030d1h60 | 
    |  2 |    a |   1.0 | s030d1h60 | 
    |  3 |    a |   2.0 | s030d1h60 |     
  And some setup parameter "q"
  When the input is processed by the mock item

Scenario: The input can be validated
  Then the input will be marked as valid

Scenario: The input will be transformed
  Then the input will be trasformed into "abcdef"
```

I know this isn't specifically what you wanted, but it's something that worked for me as a first attempt at doing some BDD-like stuff in Scala. Hope it helps.